# Do I only need to run command at once on puppet

Tags: puppet

I would like to run below command in puppet at one time for example if i had a one directory(/tmp/example) which contains **example-releases-88.99.05-rc1.tar.gz** file only coming at certain point. Only on that time need to move new name(example-releases-stable.tar.gz) and extarct it, otherwise **example-releases-stable.tar.gz** will not move at any time.

```
exec { 'fetching_example_tarball':
  cwd     => '/tmp/example',
  command =>  "mv /tmp/example/example-releases-* /tmp/example/example-releases-stable.tar.gz && sleep 5m"
  path    => ['/usr/bin', '/usr/sbin',],
}
```

Above snippet running only when the file creates **example-releases-88.99.05-rc1.tar.gz** otherwise need to skip.

The problem is second time while running puppet getting error because of move command throw error like **same file not able to move**.

Could you please help on that ?

Thanks,